# Updating State of type Array<Object> in ReactJS without mutation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, immutability

I have an array of objects with meta information.
Here is the schema for a object.

```
       this.state.slotData [{
        availability: boolean,
        id: number,
        car: {
            RegistrationNumber : string,
            Color: string
        }, {...}, {...}, ...]
```

Now, for any incoming car, I record car details
I am further checking if any slots are available, and if so, updating the **slotData** state.
I **filter()** the slotData to find all available slots then refer availableSlots[0] to access the id of the nearest empty slot.
Now, I just have to update **this.state.slotData** without mutating it.

Comment: Is `car` property a single object or array of objects ? Or maybe your structure is malformed. Does each slot have the follow 3 props `availability: boolean, id: number, car: Array<Car>` ?

Comment: I don't understand, how do you update a property without mutating it? To mutate something literally means to change its value.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine What the OP meant by mutating it is mutating the same object reference in place

Comment: @Sushanth-- Yea, each slot is entitled to have 3 props.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply immutable update and add car as a single object in slotData array you should first spread whole slotData array and than add car object like this:

```
const updatedSlotData = [...slotData, carObj];
this.setState({ slotData: updatedSlotData });
```

As long as you make a copy first, you can safely mutate the copy.

Comment: Other than adding car details, I need to update the availability as `false`, which initially was `true`.
Also, slotData is an array of objects containing multiple objects of the mentioned schema in the question. I have to pin point to a particular index and perform whats needed!